# NavLink not redirecting, if accessed directly

Tags: react-router, react-router-dom

I'm using react-router on a page with navbar and content.

```
const App = () => (
  <Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
      <Route path="/shape/:activeTab" component={Shapes} />
      <Redirect from="/shape" to="/shape/triangle" />
    </Switch>
  </Router>
);
```

-- Shapes

```
class Shapes extends React.Component {

getActiveTab() {
    switch (this.props.match.params.activeTab) {
      case 'triangle':
        return Triangle;
      case 'circle':
        return Circle;
      case 'square':
        return Square;
      default:
        return Triangle;
    }
  } 
render() {
    return (
      <div className="wrapper">
        // this is where the navbar renders. 
        <ul>
        <li>
          <NavLink exact to={`/shape/triangle`}> Triangle </NavLink>
        </li>,
        <li>
          <NavLink exact to={`/shape/circle`}> Circle </NavLink>
        </li>,
        <li>
          <NavLink exact to={`/shape/square`}> Square </NavLink>
        </li>,
      </ul>

        // this is where the content renders. 
        <div className="content">
          {
            this.getActiveTab().data.map(tuple =>
              <div>
                {tuple.description}
              </div>,
            )
          }
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
};
```

Now, when I click `localhost:8080/shape` I get redirected to proper page with navigation.
Also the navigation works properly (i:e. clicking on Triangle redirects me to `localhost:8080/shape/triangle`)

But, when I try to access the page `localhost:8080/shape/triangle` directly, I get a 404!

It works only when I access the `/shapes` page first and then use the navigation.

What do I need to address here to make sure I can route to `shape/*` pages.

Note: I'm referring https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Switch